# How to write Linq2Sql statement to sort several column in cascading way?

Tags: linq-to-sql

I've  3 columns that I'd like to sort in the Excel way, i.e. sorting the first column, and for each element sorted in the first column, I'll sort the second column, and so on. Let's say I first sort alphabetically  Countries, then for each country, I sort alphabetically cities. How do I do it using Linq2Sql?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can string together a bunch of sorts.

You need to use `OrderBy` and `ThenBy`.

You can keep chaining them together to get deferred sorting until you do the `ToList`.

```
List<YourData> places = GetPlaces();
List<YourData> sortedPlaces = places.OrderBy(p => p.Country).
    ThenBy(c => c.City).
    ThenBy(s => s.SomethingElse).
    ToList();
```

Using query syntax:

```
var places = from p in db.Places
             orderby p.Country, p.City, p.SomethingElse
             select p;
```